# How do I change the arrow in the select with Chosen plugin?

Tags: html, css

so i can't figure how i change the dropdown arrow, i need to change it to another arrow:

**Original**

[image]

**How I want it to look like**

[image]

I am using Chosen plugin, i don't know if that effects in general my edits on `<select>`.

Heres the php:

```
  <div class="paistofill">  

                              <select class="form-control bfh-countries chosen-select " data-country="PT">
                                <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                                <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                                <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                                <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                                <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                                <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                                <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                                <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                                <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                                (...)
                            </select>
```

The CSS:

```
   select{
  -webkit-appearence:none;
   background-image:url("recursos/images/span/seta.png");
   background-repeat:none;
   background-position:right center;

 }
```

I though this would do the trick. Nothing changed, what can I do?

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/georgimilev01/n7rm5/)

Comment: Added, my bad, sorry

Comment: Is the fiddle related to this question? It appears to be a copy of a W3Schools tutorial :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this class in `chosen.css`

```
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;
}
```

With this image https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen-sprite.png

So change background to your image.

Comment: Yes, you can modify existing file or add new.. whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url("recursos/images/span/seta.png");
  background-repeat: none;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/5zLn765q/1/)

You have to make some changes in CSS and try to use a parent container for styling select as,

**Your CSS**,

```
select { 
    font-family: 'Hind Madurai','Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background:#F9F9F9;
    color:#111111;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size:15px;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
    width:300px; 
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    resize: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.paistofill select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:url(https://s31.postimg.org/9rchnwbwr/down_arrow.png) no-repeat #F9F9F9;
    background-position: 96% 12px;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
}

.paistofill select option {
    background:#FFFFFF;
   color:#111111;
}
```